# Pass value to flask route when dropdown list change

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask template rendered with a default value in the route function. I am trying to change the value by selecting an option in the dropdown list. I managed to get the selected value to javascript as follows.

**html template (dropdown list part only)**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-attVal="1" href="#">Opt 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-attVal="2" href="#">Opt 2</a>
<div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function () {
  var selText = $(this).text();
  var selVal = $(this).attr("data-attVal");

  console.log(selText+":"+selVal);
});
```

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def display():
    i = 1
    # do many things based on value of i

    return render_template('display.html', response = data)
```

I don't really need javascript to communicate with my `flask app.py`. That was my initial thought. But I have no idea how to proceed after this or make a call to route `/` from my html template. I need to change the value of `i` based on the dropdown list `data-attVal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this workaround. I am not confident whether this is the most elegant way to implement this.

**html template**
removed the `data-attVal` custom attribute since I didn't work with JS.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url_for('selectDisplay',id=0)}}">Opt1</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url_for('selectDisplay',id=1)}}">Opt2</a>
<div>
```

**app.py**

I created an extra route to handle the query string value.

```
@app.route('/select', methods=['GET','POST'])
def selectDisplay():
     i = int(request.args.get('id'))
     # do things according to value of i

     return render_template('display.html', response = deserialized_bug_data['list_of_turns'])
```